# Complexity/decidability of the "nested maze" problem?

Tags: time-complexity, computation-theory

In [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/58255/deusovi-honeypot) Puzzling SE post, there's a maze with infinitely nested inside itself. Inspired by this, consider the following graph problem:

Setup:

1. A graph `G` with vertices `V` and undirected edges `E`
2. And *additional* set of directed edges `F`.
3. Starting vertex `S`
4. Goal vertex `Z`

We can define the nested maze problem using the above notation by saying you must find a path from state `(S, 0)` to state `(Z, 0)`, using the edges from `E` and `F` as follows:

1. An edge `(u, v)` in `E` lets you make the state transitions: `(u, n) -> (v, n)` or `(v, n) -> (u, n)` for any `n >= 0`. This corresponds to ordinary movement in the maze.
2. An edge `(u, v)` in `F` lets you make the state transitions: `(u, n) -> (v, n + 1)` or `(v, n + 1) -> (u, n)` for any `n >= 0`. This corresponds to entering/exiting the nested maze, with the second element of the state tracking the "depth".

A path is a sequence of edges (repetitions are allowed!).

Is there an algorithm for solving this problem in general? It seems possible that it's undecidable, but the particular example from the above Puzzling post isn't particularly hard to analyze.

Edit: Thinking about this more, can you discard E by just merging all vertices that are mutually reachable in G. Then, the problem is just one on V and F, where you want to find a path (possibly involving repeated edges) using edges either forwards or backwards, with the number of forward traversals equalling the number of backward traversals. Additionally, the number of forward traversals must be at least the number of backward traversals for all prefixes of the path.

Comment: The problem is a little bit underspecified, but (assuming at least that an edge cannot be used more than once in the solution) the short answer is simply yes, as long as the graph is finite: indeed, exhaustive search would find a solution if any.  No?  (What are you exactly asking if not just that?)

Comment: I've updated the question to make it clear that repeated use of edges is allowed. The state space is infinite so exhaustive search is off the table (in the motivating example linked at the top, there is no solution).

Comment: If each vertex has only finite number of edges connected to it, and there is a path between two vertices, then it can be found with BFS (even if the graph is infinite). If there is no path, then proving it may or may not be undecidable.

Comment: Yeah I think the interesting question is about the decision problem

Comment: This looks like **a lot** of work :)  I think I'd start by trying to prove that, given the specific constraints, repetition of cycles is always eliminable, IOW that there is never need to reuse edges: and, if so, we'd be back to it's definitely decidable... as long as the total number of nodes is finite, or at least the size of the connected components!  Namely, if the number of nodes in a connected component can be infinite, I just don't see way to guarantee bounded search (which I am taking to be a requirement for "decidability")... no?

Comment: My gut feeling that it should be decidable in this case. First we contract each connected component. Now we have a normal digraph, only we also can go back along each edge. When we go forward we add 1 to the current level, when we go back we subtract 1. We need to figure out if we can start at the beginning and reach a certain node at level 0. We can associate a set of reachable levels with each node, and the basic idea is that this set should be computable (it should be a finite union of arithmetic progressions or something like that).

Comment: Yeah I think if you build up the sequence of reachable nodes at each level from both the start and the end vertices, that set must eventually become periodic, so then you only have to check a finite number of cases. Nice!

Comment: But there is no constraint in the given problem such that we are guaranteed any periodicity in the graph, is there?  Indeed, using the given rules, I think (I might be wrong, I haven't actually worked it out) I could concoct a counter-example, i.e. an example of a graph where the search cannot terminate, even a search from both ends.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio The set of nodes reachable at level N is the result of applying the map defined by F to the reachable set at level N-1. I believe this has to eventually become periodic, because the domain is finite.

Comment: So you claimed periodic and I say "where?", now you even claim "the domain is finite", and I don't even know what we are talking about anymore...  Merry Christmas.  :)

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio Sorry that was too brief, I'll elaborate. First (see my edit to the post) merge all the nodes that are reachable from each other in `(V, E)`. 
At depth 0, the path starts at node `S`, so define `V_0 = {S}`. Let `V_N = {v  | v is reachable from a node in V_(N-1)}`. `V_N` is periodic in `N` because there are only `2^|V|` possible values. Define `U_N` analogously by starting with `U_0 = {Z}` and using backward edges from `F`. The question is then whether there is a value of `N` such that the intersection of `V_N` and `U_N` is non-empty.

Comment: Those are the definitions I have been myself referencing, and 1) I don't see where you get that "there are only 2^|V| possible values" from, and 2) even less I see how that, which would be "recursive", then becomes "period"...  Never mind, I will put together that counter-example if I manage.

Comment: Sorry, of course I meant <<then becomes "periodic">>.

Comment: 2^|V| is the size of the power set of V. That is the maximum number of values of the "reachable node set" for a given level.

Comment: @DavisYoshida  I'd like to try and actually solve this, but I think you should clarify a point once and for all: the title of your question says "nested maze" (with reference to a previous puzzle), which indeed entails "periodic", but there is nothing "nested" (that I can see) in the specification you have actually given in the question.  Could you please confirm if I should take the rules as they are specified at this point (where there is no nesting)?

Comment: The setup I stated models the example from the linked puzzle.SE post

Comment: You are still *not* justifying that claim... which indeed I think is wrong: I'll prove it when I find the time.

Comment: I'm pretty confused about what the issue is. The undirected edge set E models connections which do not traverse nesting levels, and the directed edge set F models connections which do.

Comment: You are the one who simply won't reply to the point.  That said, even you said it's not the same problem: "Inspired by this, consider the following graph problem", and the problem you have given here indeed is (not only underspecified, it's) *not* periodic/self-similar!  But I have been raising objections for days now, and you just keep repeating your claims without any justification/reasons...  The simple answer to your question I had given initially: the problem YOU have given HERE is (in general) NOT "decidable", and that's even easy to prove.  And I'll leave it at that: a poor question.

Comment: I'll just write out my answer as a full answer

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio btw I'm not even 100% sure the proof strategy I described above works. If you have a demonstration that it's undecidable please do post it and I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @JulioDiEgidio I've posted a reduction which shows it's decidable

Comment: @DavisYoshida  Nice, now I should check if it's the same problem... :)  No, seriously, thanks for that, interesting, I'll look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably overkill, but given that there hasn't been an answer here's a method of showing that this problem is decidable.

Given an instance of this problem, you can pretty easily define a pushdown automaton which defines a non-empty language iff there's a solution to the instance. Here's how to do so:

- States: The vertices of the graph with one additional state added: `V U {v_reject}`.
- Input alphabet: The set of ordered triples `{(u, v, d): u, v in V, d in {-1, 0, 1}}`.
- Stack alphabet: A singleton set `{1}`
- Transitions:

  - For each `(u, v)` in `E`, add a transition from `u` to `v` when reading an input of `(u, v, 0)`, and vice versa for an input of `(v, u, 0)`. Both transitions should leave the stack untouched.
  - For each `(u, v)` in `F`, add a transition from `u` to `v` when reading an input of `(u, v, 1)`. This transition should push a `1` onto the stack.
  - For each `(u, v)` in `F`, add a transition from `v` to `u` when reading an input of `(u, v, -1)`, which pops a `1` from the stack, but only if the stack is non-empty.
  - For any inputs other than those handled by the three cases above, transition to `v_reject`.
- Initial/final states: `S` and `Z`

Any solution to the original instance defines an input accepted by this PDA, and vice versa. In the original problem, the states consist of a vertex and a natural number. In the PDA formulation, the state is just a vertex, and the second element of the state tuple is tracked by the size of the stack.

Because CFG emptiness is decidable, this problem is decidable as well.